# Librsync: Win10 and Win8/Win7 Different results

Tags: c, windows-7, windows-10, rsync, librsync

I'm using librsync for generating binary patches and send them to another users.
But i faced a problem: on some files on win8/win7 checksum (sha512) after applying patch differs from checksum after applying patch on win10.
librsync build with msvc 14 64 bit.

I tried build librsync on win10 and on win8 - no result.

I tried use same libs (api-ms-*) on all systems - no result.

Trouble file - file with graphics resource. 
With other files library works well: checksums are same on win10 and win8.

How can i fix it?

Comment: Too broad for a C question.

Comment: Same problem here, but mine works in debug mode! also in release mode with CRT : Multi-threaded debug dll.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'd say too specific for a C question, it's nonetheless also a C question.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem is related to a bug in CRT, I fixed the issue by adding `rewind(f);` before the `fseek` in the `rs_file_copy_cb` function inside the `fileutil.c`, please try this and let me know, it fixed on my PC.